# What Sorcerer guidelines have changed since printing?

Tags: sorcerer-rpg

I've seen a few references where [Sorcerer](http://adept-press.com/role-playing-games/sorcerer/) play advice has changed since the rules were published, or where Ron Edwards refers to a section of text in the main books as unhelpful.

How is Sorcerer play supposed to be different from what is written in the books?  Is there anywhere online that I can find the 'evolved' guidelines with reference to what they're replacing?

Answer (score 6):

Just this year he's released [the Annotated Sorcerer](http://adept-press.com/buying-things/) - a version where you have the original text + commentary on the facing page, most of it is clarification but there are a couple of very useful changes.

The biggest one is the addition of "starting statements" to start the campaign.  The GM produce a statement of location/feel and a statement of how sorcery looks.  Otherwise there's a few small changes to a couple of powers - notably removing stuff like exact range calculations for a few of them, "inherent" abilities to Demon Types do count towards it's total power, etc.

Otherwise it's mostly clarifications now that in 2013, he's got the language to describe what he was trying to do before stuff like "narration trading" or "scene framing" were really well described back in 2001.  Although the rules changes are minor, the game advice about how to RUN Sorcerer in the annotated version is quite excellent.

Answer (score -2):

The biggest one is that Ron has abandoned the GSN model presented in the "System Matters" essay in Sorcerer.

Some printings note some revisions to rules; I've a revised hardcover, and it makes note of a few changes, but I've had it for years. Since I've not run it, and it's particularly esoteric, I haven't kept up with it.

Comment: Are you saying he's abandoned GNS in any form, or just the form in "System Matters," or just the form in "System Matters" with respect to the Sorcerer RPG? Can you point to some thread or comment he made that makes you think he's done this?

Comment: The essay and its mode d'employ. He's reused the labels in Big Model, but it appears big model is utterly useless psychobable. GSN as presented in System Matters is a useful predictive tool. Big Model is a descriptive tool only.